# Silverlight 4.0 is getting closer to WPF?

Tags: wpf

I am developing WPF applications and playing with Silverlight for fun. If you had experience with both WPF and Silverlight older versions can you tell if in 4.0 are they getting closer or growing apart?

What about Silverlight for Windows Phone 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete list of differences:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 is a **branch of a subset** of Silverlight 3 from what I was told at a WP7 developer event.